# Fetching a json file in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

There are few solutions on SO, but apparently they are deprecated. Angular 2 changes all the time...

Im trying to fetch a json file to my file.

There's a `items.json` file.

I'm wondering if I am able to make this work in just one file? I mean, just inside the `app.component.ts`? `app.component.ts` file actually looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


@Injectable()
export class AppServices{

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    let obj;
     this.getJSON().subscribe(data => obj=data, error => console.log(error));
  }

  public getJSON(): {
    return this.http.get("./items.json")
      .map((res:any) => res.json())
  }
}

export class AppComponent {
    let items = getJSON();
  }
}
```

**Or maybe** I have to include a `app.service.ts` file? And drop there the code fetching the json? It was so easy to do it in Angular1, why they made this so complicated...

**I'm looking for the shortest solution as it is possible** I will upvote every answer. Thank u in advance

**EDIT** 
I got another code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'watchlist',
  templateUrl: './watchlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./watchlist.component.css']
})


export class WatchlistComponent {

  data;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.http.get('items.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());
  }

}
```

How to load this data into my items variable?

Comment: "Another code" looks good. But if you type the 'data' variable, it will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// A function You can declare an app

```
app() {
    return this.http.get('/config.json');
  }

 this.app().subscribe((data: any) => {
 }
```